# Jupyter Erroneous Environments Showing up in Conda tab with `nb_conda` extension

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda

Not sure how to fix this, or how it got corrupted. This is conda on a jupyterhub install.

Error Message:

> EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment

Pics Below:

Image from `Conda` tab (there is an redundant `anaconda3` env showing up):

[image]

Image of error when loading:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This is [a confirmed bug](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda/issues/66) in `nb_conda` for `conda version >=4.4`:

> The reason is the change of `conda info --json` output. Fresh installation of version 4.3.33 gives `envs=[]`, version >=4.4 gives `envs=[root_env_dir]` (always non empty).

It's not fixed in current released version yet (`nb_conda 2.2.1`), but we can fix this bug manually, by changing the [current bug code base](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda/blob/c27196f15528b92c808cff1123a7579ba046d180/nb_conda/envmanager.py#L84) in your local machine: `~/anaconda3/pkgs/nb_conda-2.2.1-py36h349edbb_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nb_conda/envmanager.py`, note that your own anaconda root dir (`~/anaconda3`) and pkgs build version(`py36h349edbb_0`) might be different.

FROM:

```
    return {
        "environments": [root_env] + [get_info(env)
                                      for env in info['envs']]
    }
```

TO:

```
    return {
        "environments": [root_env] + [get_info(env) for env in info['envs']
                                      if env != root_env['dir']]
    }
```

Then, shut down any jupyter notebook server and restart one, the `anaconda3` env will gone.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I try to change the code but it;s still same error. and environment anaconda3 still exist. is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This is either a bug in `nbconda`, ot a stale kernelspec file.
to fix it check whether `/home/user/.conda/envs/anaconda3 exists`, if it does remove it.

Issue a `jupyter kernelspec list` in a terminal, for me it gives:

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  code_scattering    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/code_scattering
  meetup             /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/meetup
  octave             /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/octave
  python2            /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
  python3            /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
  pythonroot         /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/pythonroot
```

it should list all kernelspec and their location. 
Find the corresponding env and delete the folder.